# How can I calculate the suggested installation directory at installer runtime?

Tags: java, install4j

I tried setting an installer variable with a custom script, but then noticed that the 'Directory name' and 'Custom base directory' fields in the media wizard do not accept installer variables.

I also tried not using the 'Custom base directory' option in the media wizard, and setting the `sys.installationDir` variable with a custom script just before the 'Installation location' screen, but it seems like that screen computes the install dir based on the media wizard settings.

[image]

Context: We build a production and a test installer. The prod version should suggest to install in `sys.programFilesDir`. The test installer does not request privileges and should suggest to install in the user home.

A compiler variable is defined to distinguish between prod and test version.

Answer (score 1):

Never mind, setting the `sys.installationDir` after the `Welcome-screen` but before the `Installation location-screen` does seem to work after all.

The `Only if undefined-option` needs to be unchecked, because the `Welcome-screen` seems to always initialize this variable. Unfortunately this means that for upgrade installations where the user opts to choose a new install dir, this script also runs and will not show the previous install dir (seems to be an ok trade-off).

[image]